# Parentheses in Lyx not working properly

Tags: math-mode, lyx

When I insert parentheses with this formula in Lyx, they are too long. How can I fix it?

[image: Parentheses are too long]

Comment: parenthesis are vertically centred so what you show is the expected outout, there was a recent question on this with alternative layouts shown I'll see if I can find the link...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use the `pmatrix` environment in the place of `\left( … \right)`.

Comment: not th eone I was thinking of but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347193/how-to-remove-the-upper-space-above-frac-in-left-right

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps that you were thinking about [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/606331/134805).

Comment: Thanks Bernard, the `pmatrix` worked perfectly

Comment: @Bernard perhaps copy/paste your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Bernard if you copy/paste it I will accept the answer